# $n$-th derivative of $\frac{e^x−1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Consider the function $g(x) = \frac{e^x-1}{x}$. Find a general formula for $g^{(n)}(x)$ (i.e. the $n-th$ derivative of $g(x)$) and prove that this formula is correct.

- I just want to ask can I use, finding the sum of a series by  differentiating or should I use they Taylor series

Comment: You may also use the [general Leibniz/product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)

Comment: @Peter Szilas : you give a self reference to the question.

Comment: Jean Marie.Oops.This question was asked yesterday.Yves Daoust gave a nice answer.Thought I had copied yesterday's link.Thanks, Peter

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245022/nth-derivative-of-fracex−1x/3245036#3245036

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\exp(x) =1+x+x^2/2!+...$ and the Taylor expansion of a function $g(x)$ evaluated at $x=0$ is given by

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {g^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a closed form involving only finite sum. Write $g$ as

$$ g(x) = \int_{0}^{1} e^{xs} \, \mathrm{d}s. $$

Then for $n \geq 1$, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^n}{n!}g^{(n)}(x)
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n s^n}{n!} e^{xs} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \left[ \frac{x^{n-1} s^n}{n!} e^{xs} \right]_{s=0}^{s=1} - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n-1}s^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{xs} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}e^x - \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}g^{(n-1)}(x).
\end{align*}

Solving this recurrence relation yields

\begin{align*}
g^{(n)}(x) = (-1)^n \frac{n!}{x^{n+1}} \left( e^x \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \frac{x^k}{k!}\right) - 1 \right)
\end{align*}

We remark that this is also easily derived from Leibniz product rule.